# How to achieve idempotence when we execute bash script in ruby/knife environment?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, knife

I am trying to execute bash script in knife/Ruby environment. For example:

```
cookbook_file "test.sh"  do
  path "/tmp/test.sh"
  mode "755"
  action :create
end

bash "execute test.sh on #{nodeName}" do
  code <<-EOH
    sh test.sh arg1 arg2 
  EOH
  #only_if { false }
end
```

How can I use `only_if` or `not_if`? So when we execute second time and the contents of "test.sh" is not changed, it should skip execution. I am getting this:

```
* cookbook_file[test.sh] action create (up to date)
```

but it still executes second time, third time...

Comment: Do you mean that `test.sh` is potentially different every time the resource runs, and you want to run `test.sh` only if it's changed since the last time it was run?

Comment: test.sh is same. And I want to run only when it is changed. How can I use only_if/not_if and file checksums. Or some other way.

Comment: I have this too: cookbook_file "test.sh"  do
  path "/tmp/test.sh"
  mode "755"
  action :create
end

Answer (score 4):

You wouldn't use a guard, instead you would use a notification:

```
execute 'run test' do
  action :nothing
  command 'bash /tmp/test.sh arg1 arg2'
end

cookbook_file "test.sh"  do
  path "/tmp/test.sh"
  mode "755"
  notifies :run, 'execute[run test]', :immediately
end
```

Notifications trigger when a resources updates, so any time the cookbook file changes, it will run the `execute`. Also you want to be using `execute` instead of `bash` or `script` because you are running a command rather than an inline script file.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. It is excellent answer and with great explanation. Once again thank you very much.